# How to setup a domain name server on CentOS?

Tags: linux, dns, centos, domain-name, nameservers

I deploy a site and try to login, for instance on **www.website.com**, but there is no login info when I go to **website.com**

How to make both domain as same?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a domain name server to accomplish this, you can simply use a .htaccess file.

Inside the file, put the lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What this does is looks at the URL entered by the user, and if it does not start with `www.` then it prepends it to the URL and redirects. So entering in **website.com**, will redirect to **www.website.com**.